# Move existing windows installation to new computer, *without* original computer?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My laptop died, but the hard drive is fine. I would like to buy a new laptop and move the hard drive to the new laptop, keeping my windows installation, with all its installed programs. Is this possible? Since the old laptop is toast, using sysprep is impossible. Is there any other way?

Comment: It is indeed possible.  Tools like Acronis True Image support creating an image of the hdd then using what basically is sysprep to allow the image to be restored on different hardware.

Comment: Right but don't tools like that require that you have already made a backup? It's a bit late for that.

Comment: No; just hook up the hdd over USB do an image then restore the image to the same hdd on the new computer that requires a storage location clearly

Comment: @Vigabrand - I'd have recommended trying to boot in Safe mode first. Maybe even Sysprep in someway if possible, maybe in a VM.